# Any way that I can parameterize sort column and sort direction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a very large stored proc, that generates a table at the end.  I need this table to be dynamically sortable by the specified column and direction.  Is there any way to do this without having to put my SQL into a string, then executing the string?  The proc is already massive, with around 15 IF statements, all of which generate the same table, but with different data depending on which IF statement gets hit, totalling around 1200 lines.  There's 12 columns, with obviously 2 sort directions, so if I were to put an IF statement in front of each of those for the @SortDirection and @SortColumn, I'd be looking at having to rewrite the procedure with 360 IF statements!

Can this be done dynamically without having to put it all into a massively complicated string, then executing that string?  I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Personally, I would have the presentation layer handle it, not SQL Server. SSRS, for example, has the option so that you can add sort buttons on your tablixes; then the user can even change the sort order post execution.

Comment: I would absolutely love to do that, but I'm maintaining a program written by someone else, and changing the presentation layer would involve downtime, which isn't an option unless absolutely necessary.  It's easier to change the DB in the background without anyone noticing any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 columns should be 24 sort expressions:

```
order by (case when @col = 'column1' and @dir = 'asc' then column1 end) asc,
         (case when @col = 'column1' and @dir = 'desc' then column1 end) desc,
         . . .
```

Not trivial, but certainly not 360 conditional expressions:

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and report back whether or not it worked.